Serilog Seq and file Sink not working in maui (net9)
I want to use Serilog with file- and seq-sink in a .NET9 Maui app but both are not working. I already used it in an asp.net core web api project and it worked fine, so i tried to implement it in a similar way.
serilog configuration:
using Serilog;

namespace StudienAppDemo;
public static class SerilogConfig
{
    public static ILogger ConfigureLogging()
    {
        return Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .MinimumLevel.Debug()
             .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
             .WriteTo.File("./logs/log-.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
             .WriteTo.Console()
             .WriteTo.Debug()
             .CreateLogger();
    }
}


Service registration in MauiProgram.cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            })
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit();

        // Configure Serilog
        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Services.AddSerilog(SerilogConfig.ConfigureLogging());

Debugging showed that serilog is the correct logging-provider and .WriteTo.Console() and .WriteTo.Debug() also work.
But file logging is not working and seq under localhost:5341 is also not getting any logging events.



EDIT:
The Problem was the "localhost:5341" instead of
.WriteTo.Seq("http://<IPv4Address>.146:5341") 

File logging though is still not working, because the FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory seems to be space on the emulator and is looking like: /data/user/0/com.companyname.app/files/database.db3
I tried the following, but this is not working. I also get no serilog.selflog errors.
.WriteTo.File(Path.Combine("C:\\data", "log-.log"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)


Try enabling the SelfLog to see if you get any further info. https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog


Working example of different Serilog sinks in Maui(.net9):

Pre-requisites

I have installed below nuget packages.

Serilog (4.1.0)
Serilog.Extensions.Hosting (8.0.0)
Serilog.Sinks.Debug (3.0.0)
Serilog.Sinks.File (6.0.0)
Serilog.Sinks.Seq (8.0.0)
Serilog.Sinks.Email (4.0.0)

Code:
I will add full code example later with my GitHub url

MauiProgram.cs

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;

namespace MauiAppWithNet9
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
            builder.Services.AddLogging(options =>
            {
                options.AddSerilog(
                    new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                    .WriteTo.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.Seq("http://10.16.1.202:5341/")
                    .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory,"MyApp.Log"),rollingInterval: (RollingInterval)RollingInterval.Day)     
                    .WriteTo.Email(options: new()
                    {
                        From = "MauiApp@test.com",
                        To = ["MauiAppSupport@test.com"],
                        Host = "smtp4dev.example.com",
                        Port = 2525
                    },
                    batchingOptions: new()
                    {
                        BatchSizeLimit=10,
                        BufferingTimeLimit=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                    })
                    .CreateLogger());
            });    

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}


MainPage.xaml.cs

using MauiAppWithNet9.Pages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MauiAppWithNet9
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        private readonly ILogger<MainPage> _logger;

        public MainPage(ILogger<MainPage> logger)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _logger = logger;
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;

            if (count == 1)
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
            else
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

            _logger.LogDebug($"*********** Current Counter:{count}");

            SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
        }

        private void OnHomePageClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("HomePage button clicked ...");
        }
    }

}

Output in file:

Output on Seq:

Output on Email:


Thanks for the example, the Problem was the "localhost:5341" instead of :5341
File logging still not working, because the FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory seems to be space on the emulator.
/data/user/0/com.companyname.app/files/database.db3

Please go through this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-9.0&tabs=android, it shows the how file system is behaving differently for different platforms. You might need ADB to access the files stored on android emulator file system. You might need to adjust your path for storing file based on your platform of choice.

adb link https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

@Dura I was having the same issue. Then I realised the log file was being created in the same folder location but with a different name. The file param, even though it says Path to the file, uses it as the folder location.
My Serilog configuration is as follows:
builder.Services
    .AddSerilog(new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "log.txt"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit:7)
    .CreateLogger());

Note the WriteTo.File, I specified AppDirectory. Not sure if "./" is the same thing.
Turns out the files are getting generated at FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory location but are following a naming pattern of log{date} e.g. log20241127.txt.
Figured this while investigating when I listed all files in that location to see what is there.
Directory.GetFiles(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory)

I hope this helps.

in my case when running the android emulator, the "FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory" seems to be some path on the andreoid emulator.... it looks like:
/data/user/0/com.companyname.app/files/database.db3
